# Dynamically set Grouping in ng-table

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am using `ng-table` to list a set of elements, and am needing to group the elements in the table.
I want to be able to redefine what the data is sorted by, (even if this means having to redefine the table), as the creation of the table is fast.
I have had a go on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYrG7/3/), but it doesn't seem to be able to update the grouping.

I aim to have something like the following:

```
1. create table using initial data, and default grouping column
2. change grouping column using a variable
3. table updates to reflect changed grouping variable
```

I thought of maybe using an `ng-if` to surround the entire ng-table, as I've read that it destroys the DOM elements inside it when evaluated to false, but this is a drastic measure to something that may be fairly easy to solve.

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYrG7/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for.
See the updated JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CYrG7/4/).

What I had to do was call the `$scope.tableParams.reload()` function.
I didn't find any documentation about this, and ended up looking through the source code.

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/CYrG7/4/)